# Url Rewrite Not seeming to work on Windows Azure?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect from the domain.net to www.domain.net. However, all I'm getting is the IIS 404 error page.

My web config looks like this. But even the http error declaration is ignored and I just get IIS's 404 page, not the file I specified.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultPath="/404.html" defaultResponseMode="Redirect" existingResponse="Replace"/>
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mylifelessons.net$" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mylifelessons.net/{R:0}"
              redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirect from the domain.net to www.domain.net is handled much easier in your registrar's domain settings - point www to your Azure DNS and the forward your root domain to www

if you insist on using a rewrite rule, use the IIS URL Rewrite module to help you create a cononical rewrite rule - output to web.config will be similar to:

```
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.test\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```